# Package for dash_table_component

Tags: python

I tried to run "from dash_table_component import Table" and it said it had no module named dash_table_component. I tried to pip install dash-table-experiments but it still showed no module for dash_table_component. I would like to ask that what Python package I should install to get this module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

from dash_table_experiments import DataTable